# Roblox Simulating Orientation During Flight

Tags: roblox

Trying to help my son with his Roblox game and new to the platform.

I have created a very simple model containing a couple of parts ( body and wings ) and attached a VehicleSeat to the body.

I can get the model to 'fly' by going forward, backward, up, down, turning etc.

What I am wondering is if there is a way to change the entire models orientation during flight

For instance when turning left I would like the model, from the perspective of the pilot in first person view to have the horizon change, and from an outside observer see the planes wing dip ( have the model change orientation around the longitudinal axis )

The outer model container does not have an accessible orientation property that I can find, and changing orientation of the main body part doesn't change the other parts ( wings stay in their original orientation )

Changing the VehcileSeat orientation has odd effects ( like ejecting the pilot and parts flying apart even though they are all welded )

It seems possible since some flight simulators do this, but having trouble figuring out where to start looking, cant find any tutorials of dev-help on their site.

Answer (score 0):

I think a bodygyro would be useful, or some other body power. look on [Roblox Wiki](http://wiki.roblox.com) for any details you need.